# Stripes UrlBinding - Parameter disappears on submit

Tags: java, stripes

I use URL bindings on all my actionbeans and some of them requires a parameter, e.g. /admin/users/123.

Taking this URL as an example, in my actionbean I am able to get the parameter 123 and display user information fine. The same page allows changes to user information and this is where the problem comes in.

On submitting the updated user information, the URL becomes /admin/users.

This is a problem because calling context.getRequest().getRequestURL() returns me /admin/users instead of /admin/users/123.

I reckon this to be due to the way the  tag is written in the jsp:

```
<stripes:form beanclass="com.name.ui.web.stripes.action.admin.UserActionBean">...</stripes:form>
```

which resolves to

```
<form action="/admin/users" method="post">...</form>
```

The corresponding actionbean is coded and annotated as such:

```
@UrlBinding("/admin/users/{userId}")
public class UserActionBean{ 
  private long userId;
  public long getUserId(){return userId;}
  public void setUserId(long userId){this.userId=userId;}
}
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

As [answered](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29742440) on the Stripes mailing list by Martin Walsh, you can use the `<stripes:param>` tag inside `<stripes:form>`. I'd add that doing a redirect-after-post (or [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)) also allows you to return to your /admin/users/123 URL.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are not using JSP (in my case I'm using Velocity) you can still just explicitly put the id (123) in the request and forward, or you can redirect-after-post as Frank indicated.